# How to submit a query request and store it in a variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, sql, json, google-fusion-tables

I'm new to SQL, JSON and Fusion Table. I want to get data from a Fusion Table and store it in a variable in javascript, so that I can append the data in a div element.

This is the javascript I got so far:

```
    var TopCity;
    TopCity = '{
          "dataSourceUrl": 'http://www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?tq=',
          "query": 
        'SELECT Location FROM 131fgSFd-cumxvMzICckXO-W4CldzfO9J9D--Vw9V ORDER BY Total_Task_Num DESC LIMIT 1',

          }';



    $("#TopCityDiv").append("<div>" + TopCity + "</div>");
```

Basically, I want to find the city with the top number of completed tasks and display the city name.

I read through the fusion table sql stuff but am still confused:
https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/sql-reference

Appreciate all help.

Update: It works!

In order to query my fusion table and not just save it in a table, I need to enable the Fusion Table API and make a public API key.

Working code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var TopCity;

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=SELECT+Location+FROM+131fgSFd-cumxvMzICckXO-W4CldzfO9J9D--Vw9V+ORDER+BY+Total_Task_Num+DESC+LIMIT+1&hdrs=false&typed=false&fields=rows&key={API Key}",

        success: function(data) {
            TopCity = data["rows"];
            $("#TopCityDiv").append("<div>" + TopCity + "</div>");
        },
        error: function(xhr, error) {
            console.log('NaN');

        }
    });

});
```

Comment: What happens when you run the code in your question?

Comment: @DanBracuk I got unexpected EOF and undefined container.

Comment: EOF in the line with TopCity = '{ if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a callback to get the data. For example, you could use code like below

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var TopCity;

        $.get('https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=SELECT Location FROM 131fgSFd-cumxvMzICckXO-W4CldzfO9J9D--Vw9V ORDER BY Total_Task_Num DESC LIMIT 1&key={your API key}', function (data, status, xhr) {
            //assign the data to TopCity for future use
            TopCity = data;

            //do something with the data here
            $.("#TopCityDiv").append("<div>" + data + "</div>");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I received this error - Missing query for request id: 0. I didn't use a product key, but I don't think that's the cause of the error.

Comment: Sure I added it in the question.

Comment: @user234159 I see. You have to use visualization lib for this. Check my edited answer

Comment: @user234159 great! You might mark my reply as answer then.